# Calculating slot width or opening

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How do I calculate the width of a slot if the overall width of the part is .310 and from the edge of the part to the center of the slot is .155?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have sufficient information to solve the question. If you have a part of 0.310 width, the center line of the part is always going to be at 0.155 from either edge. The slot width can be any dimension smaller than 0.310 within limits of the material.

The information you have provided can only determine that the slot is centered.